# What function to use to enumerate a directory's contents in Linux?

Tags: c, linux

After half an hour of reading manuals, I'd like to share my findings, seeing as many people in other questions just point to `readdir`, which is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** *Do not use `readdir` or `readdir_r`*, they're unsafe! Use `scandir`.

[`readdir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/readdir.html) is not thread-safe (in fact, it's the only directory-related function in POSIX that's known to have this flaw). You can use it in simple programs, of course, but be careful!

`readdir_r` is thread-safe, but it's godawfully painful to use, especially since you have to allocate your own `dirent` buffer, and it's not as straight-forward as you might think (because it's not guaranteed that the name of the file will fit in the provided array inside the structure on all *nixes and all file systems in all cases). [There are workarounds](http://womble.decadent.org.uk/readdir_r-advisory.html), but when you're using them, *"don't look, no matter what happens"*.

So far the only completely safe and straightforward to use function that I know of is [`scandir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scandir): it's thread-safe *and* it essentially does everything for you, leaving you with a clean array of directory entries. While it may not fit for every occasion, it definitely saves a lot of pain you'd otherwise have to endure by yourself.